# firebase hosting - terminal hangs waiting for authentication

Tags: terminal, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I just created a firebase account using my Gmail account and I want to test deploying a simple JS app to the cloud. I'm using Linux. I type in `firebase init` and the terminal says, "Waiting for authentication" then the browser opens and for a quick second I see a message "Authenticate Application" but then it disappears and asks me to login to my Google account. I login and it redirects me to my dashboard. In the terminal window it is still waiting for authentication. So the browser never tells the terminal window that I logged in and is stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have same issue, did you fix it @user441058 ?

Comment: unfortunately not. I bailed on firebase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a different thread with an answer that worked for me ([How to login to `firebase-tools` on headless remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828039/how-to-login-to-firebase-tools-on-headless-remote-server))

1. On the terminal use the following command:
   $ firebase login --no-localhost
2. A different authentication link will be generated. On any machine, open a browser and paste the link from the terminal.
3. The result is an authorization code that you now need to paste into the terminal.

Everything should work well...I hope...

Answer (score -2):

before `firebase init` you should be logged in (`firebase login`)

if you hit `firebase login`

first your cli asks permission to allow firebase

`Allow Firebase to collect anonymous CLI usage information?`

type `yes` and hit return

now an url will be generated

copy the url and open in any browser

login (if required)

if you are using first it asks for permission when you hit ok

login successful