# How to login to `firebase-tools` on headless remote server?

Tags: linux, firebase, firebase-tools

I am attempting to use `firebase-tools` on a remote Linux server via Putty. There is no desktop running on this server.

When I run `firebase login`, I'm presented with a long url that I need to copy/paste into any other device's browser:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&response_type=code&state=3kkd93kl&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9005
```

I copy/paste this into the browser on my local machine, then I authenticate with my Google account, then it attempts to redirect me to

```
http://localhost:9005/?state=25744816&code=4/mz.....
```

which is not an actual server running on my machine and is defintely not the address to the remote machine, which doesn't even have port 9005 active.

So the result is that the terminal is still sitting at "Waiting for authentication..."

I see a command called `login:ci` which says its for non-interactive environments, but it appears to do the same thing as the `login` command.

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use `firebase login --no-localhost`

It will then prompt a url you can visit from any browser (no matter the machine), like your host.

[image: Log in url prompt response]

Log in with your Google account as usual and accept the permission request.

Finally, copy the provided **authorization code**

[image: The authorization code of the url you visited]

And paste it back in your remote machine's terminal. You should get a success message.

Comment: I use codenvy.io for all my workspace setup and was struggling with issue for so long. Thanks for our help :)

Comment: Works great for Docker container, you don't need to open additional port (9005) just for OAuth callback

Answer (score 1):

Procedure on how to setup Firebase for CI and headless servers is described here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#using-with-ci-systems

> The Firebase CLI requires a browser to complete authentication, but is fully compatible with CI and other headless environments.
>
> 1. On a machine with a browser, install the Firebase CLI.
> 2. Run firebase `login:ci` to log in and print out a new refresh token (the current CLI session will not be affected).
> 3. Store the output token in a secure but accessible way in your CI system.
>
> There are two ways to use this token when running Firebase commands:
>
> 1. Store the token as the environment variable `FIREBASE_TOKEN` and it will be automatically used.
> 2. Run all commands with `--token <token>` flag in your CI system.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase respects your standard GCP Oauth2 token.

Having to go to the browser and get the code doesn't seem very CI or headless.

This is working for us:

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json 
 # Where key.json is your service account json file

export FIREBASE_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)